# Material UI: Set focus color in theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Can someone please show me how to set the color used when an input has focus.

I tried the following which did not work.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#cc0000',
    },
    action: {
      focus: '#cc0000'
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

primary color is used at input's border when focused.

so, did you use `ThemeProvider` to customize?